# Western Digital External 2.5 disk use SATA or PATA?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata, pata

I would like to know if an external disk I have, which HD Tune tells me is a **WD800BEVS** from **Western Digital** is **SATA** or **PATA**?

I would like to be sure it is SATA before removing it from the box (and probably destroy it) and put in a new external box with **eSATA connector**.

Do you have any information about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on Google tells me it's a [WD Scorpio Blue SATA drive](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.asp?driveid=202) (80 GB, SATA 1.5 Gb/s, 8 MB Cache, 5400 RPM).

But it's not the external drive itself, it's the model of the internal drive that is located inside the external enclosure.

So it should definitely fit inside another enclosure with a eSata connector.

Comment: Your are right, I saw the model code, thank you :D